# Mutation error in Vuex store even though I am not mutating state directly

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, vuex

I am fetching data from firebase and I need to store it to the vuex store, when I run the action which gets the data and commits a mutation which will put that data into the state I get this error `Error: "[vuex] do not mutate vuex store state outside mutation handlers."` even though I am not mutating the state directly.

If somebody can help me figure this, I am losing my head over this error.

`actions.js`

```
export function GET_CARDS_FROM_FIREBASE({ commit }) {
    const cardsArray = [];

    DB.collection('cards')
        .get()
        .then(querySnapshot => {
            querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
                doc.data()
                    .broker.get()
                    .then(brokersData => {
                        const cardInfo = {
                            firebase_card_id: doc.id,
                            trello_id: doc.data().trello_id,
                            address: doc.data().address,
                            bbl: doc.data().bbl,
                            bblMapLink: doc.data().bblMapLink,
                            broker: brokersData.data(),
                            date: doc.data().date,
                            time: doc.data().time,
                            dwnBroker: doc.data().dwnBroker,
                            dwnExterior: doc.data().dwnExterior,
                            dwnInterior: doc.data().dwnInterior,
                            dwnNeighborhood: doc.data().dwnNeighborhood,
                            gMapLink: doc.data().gMapLink,
                            meetingPlace: doc.data().meetingPlace,
                            notes: doc.data().notes
                        };
                        cardsArray.push(cardInfo);
                    })
            });

            console.log('cards array', cardsArray);
            commit('SET_CARDS', cardsArray);
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
}
```

`mutations.js`

```
export function SET_CARDS(state, cards) {
    state.cards = cards
}
```

`getters.js`

```
export function GET_CARDS (state) {
    return state.cards
}
```

`state.js`

```
export default {
  cards: []
}
```

`component`

```
<template>
    <q-page class="flex flex-center column">
        {{ GET_CARDS }}
    </q-page>
</template>

<style>
</style>

<script>
import { mapGetters } from 'vuex'

export default {
    name: "assignments",
    computed: {
      ...mapGetters('assignments', ['GET_CARDS'])
    }
};
</script>
```

Comment: How are you using `cards` in your .vue component? You can't associate this value to a v-model because you would being mutating vuex store outside a mutation

Comment: I am just displaying them on a page with getter see the question updated with component code.

Comment: I would try make a copy inside mutation, like `state.cards = [...cards]`

Comment: it just passes an empty array to the state

Comment: No. It passes a copy of your cards array, received by parameter